# How can I create a custom inspector guilayout.toggle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Control))]
public class ControlEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        Control control = (Control)target;

        if (GUILayout.Toggle(control.isControl, "Control"))
        {
            control.ToControl();
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public bool isControl = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void ToControl()
    {
        if(isControl == false)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(rigidbody);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is a guilayout.toggle or a button and to be able to destroy and to add a Rigidbody to the gameobject the Control script will be on.

How do I create back add the Rigidbody to the gameobject ?

And how do I use the isControl flag ? The idea is to use the guilayout.toggle in the editor script.

I want to destroy or add a new rigidbody while the game is running ! But using a guilayout.toggle or button in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you wouldn't need an inspector script for that at all. Simply add a repeadetly check for the bool like e.g. in `LateUpdate` and make the component [`[ExecuteInEditoMode]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) like

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditoMode]
public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public bool isControl;

    // repeatedly check the bool
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        ToControl();
    }

    public void ToControl()
    {
        if (!isControl && rigidbody)
        {
            // in editmode use DestroyImmediate
            if (Application.isEditor && !Application.isPlaying)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(rigidbody);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(rigidbody);
            }

            rigidbody = null;
        }
        else if(isControl && !rigidbody)
        {
            rigidbody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

            // adjust settings of rigidbody
        }
    }
}
```

This way `LateUpdate` is called both, in playmode and in editmode, and will simply react to the `isControl` value.

---

Ofcourse there is an overhead for calling this `LateUpdate` all the time so if you want to avoid it you can call it only from the editor. However, since you are using `base.OnInspectorGUI();` you don't really need an additional `Toggle` since you already have the one of the default inspector.

So could simply do

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public bool isControl;

    public void ToControl()
    {
        if (!isControl && rigidbody)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor && !Application.isPlaying)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(rigidbody);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(rigidbody);
            }

            rigidbody = null;
        }
        else if(isControl && !rigidbody)
        {
            rigidbody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
    }
}
```

and in the editor script simply do

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Control))]
public class ControlEditor : Editor
{
    private Control control;

    // calle when the object gains focus
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        control = (Control)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (!control.isControl && control.rigidbody)
        {
            control.ToControl();
            Repaint();
        }
        else if (control.isControl && !control.rigidbody)
        {
            control.ToControl();
            Repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT** you will already notice that this might affect how Undo/Redo works - in this case it would e.g. reset the `isControl` value but not remove along the `RigidBody` component leading to errors (see more below)

---

Or since you asked it you can add the ToggleField (currently you will have it twice since one also ships with `base.OnInspectorGUI();`)

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Control))]
public class ControlEditor : Editor
{
    private Control control;

    // calle when the object gains focus
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        control = (Control)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        control.isControl = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("additional isControl", control.isControl);

        if (!control.isControl && control.rigidbody)
        {
            control.ToControl();
            Repaint();
        }
        else if (control.isControl && !control.rigidbody)
        {
            control.ToControl();
            Repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT** you will notice that this solution changing the value using the `additional isControl` lacks the possibility of using Undo/Redo completely and it will **NOT** mark your scene as "dirty" so Unity might not save those changes!

---

So **if** you really want to have your custom toggle field in an inspector script I would actually recommend strongly to use proper [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html)s instead of directly making changes to the `target` (sometimes it can't be avoided like with the adding of the component though):

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Control))]
public class ControlEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _isControl;
    private SerializedProperty rigidbody;
    private Control control;

    // calle when the object gains focus
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        control = (Control)target;

        // link serialized property
        _isControl = serializedObject.FindProperty("isControl");
        rigidbody = serializedObject.FindProperty("rigidbody");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        // load current values into the serialized copy
        serializedObject.Update();

        if (!_isControl.boolValue && rigidbody.objectReferenceValue)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(rigidbody.objectReferenceValue);
            rigidbody.objectReferenceValue = null;
        }
        else if (_isControl.boolValue && !rigidbody.objectReferenceValue)
        {
            var rb = control.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigidbody.objectReferenceValue = rb;
        }

        // write back changed serialized values to the actual values
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

This looks more complicated and actually you have duplicate code but it gives you full Undo/Redo support and marks your objects and scenes dirty so Unity saves the changes.